# zero-ending attributive adjective before a language name

Tags: adjective, adverb

So I've stumbled upon the following phrase:

> Er ist so müde, dass er nur langsam Deutsch sprechen kann.

My question is why is langsam used without an ending? I'm aware that language names in German have two forms, and here, it's the neuter zero-article one. But my grammar books have no mention of anything pertained to my specific question. Is this even correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not used attributively here, *langsam* is an adverb in this sentence. Not his German is slow, his speaking is.

> He is so tired that he can only speak German slowly.

You're completely correct that it would have an ending if it was used attributively:

> ... dass er nur langsames Deutsch sprechen kann.